# search data from a large json data using loops

Tags: jquery, html, json, cordova

i am implementing a location page that contains two dropdowns(states and cities).i have list of states and cities(total 40000 objects) in json format.i am eable to get values from json but it takes much time to get loaded into html dropdown.Give a simple solution that doesn't take much time to iterate through that much of data..

Comment: i want to use for large objects script

Comment: _"Give a simple solution..."_ - Well, since you asked so nicely...

Comment: already i am using for loop(var in json obj) that it was unresponsive

Answer (score 0):

Using a dropdown list of such 40k objects is simply unusable. You should break down the bits of data and do some logic based on user input to search and bring the user some suggestions.

Comment: sorry but can't understand what do you mean

Comment: e tane nai samjay badak tu haju nano chho

Answer (score 0):

use ajax and eval() function.

```
success: function (data) {
              data=eval("("+data+")");


    //$.each(data, function(var x){
     for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
```